# Trigger behavior with Field Update

Tags: apex, trigger, field-update

Well today while working with triggers I observed a weird issue.
In my org I have a object called `Demo__c` and which has a standard "Name" field and another field called "TimeStamp__c". I have a following trigger on this object .

```
    trigger DemoTrigger on Demo__c (before update,after update) {
    for(Demo__c demo : trigger.new){
        if(demo.name!=trigger.oldMap.get(demo.Id).name){
            System.debug('New-->'+demo.name+'<-------'+trigger.oldMap.get(demo.Id).name);
        }
        else{
            System.debug('#######SAME##############');
        }
    }
}
```

And a worflow that updates the "TimeStamp__c" field everytime the record is updated.
So when am updating the "Name" field what I was expecting is to see this line `"New-->'+demo.name+'<-------'+trigger.oldMap.get(demo.Id).name"` in the debug and when the workflow is firing I was expecting `#######SAME##############` since this will invoke the trigger again but somehow things are adding up after field am seeing `"New-->'+demo.name+'<-------'+trigger.oldMap.get(demo.Id).name"` again in the debug. Am really confused just wanted to know if it is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I have also asked a question about this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/109/workflow-rule-causing-trigger-to-fire-twice I feel your pain, it is not what I expected either

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).  What you observed is the expected behavior.

Here are the relevant steps.

> (3) Executes all before triggers.
>
> (6) Executes all after triggers.
>
> (9) Executes workflow rules
>
> (10) If there are workflow field updates, updates the record again.
>
> (11) If the record was updated with workflow field updates, fires before and after triggers one more time (and only one more time), in
> addition to standard validations. Custom validation rules are not run
> again.
>
> Note: The before and after triggers fire one more time only if something needs to be updated. If the fields have already been set to a value, the triggers are not fired again.

Followed by the following statement about Trigger.old.

> Trigger.old contains a version of the objects before the specific
> update that fired the trigger. However, there is an exception. When a
> record is updated and subsequently triggers a workflow rule field
> update, Trigger.old in the last update trigger won’t contain the
> version of the object immediately prior to the workflow update, but
> the object before the initial update was made.

With the following example:

> For example, suppose an existing record has a number field with an
> initial value of 1. A user updates this field to 10, and a workflow
> rule field update fires and increments it to 11. In the update trigger
> that fires after the workflow field update, the field value of the
> object obtained from Trigger.old is the original value of 1, rather
> than 10, as would typically be the case.

So, in your case the following occurred:

1. Execute before update: Different.
2. Execute after update: Different.
3. Workflow rule update.
4. Execute before update: Different, because of exception to the rule.
5. Execute after update: Different, because of exception to the rule.