# Unable to Delete the records/rows in Trigger

Tags: apex, exception

I have trigger it working in Sandbox.It delete the records when the field "Delete__c" check box is checked.I have tested 200 rows,Trigger deleted rows in sandbox but the same scenario in production their are using apex data-loader update **Bid__c** Object with 250 records.Each Bid__c have 4 to 7 Bid_line__c that means my trigger can delete the 1300+ rows approximately .See the following code for trigger,It working in GUI.Can someone please tell me why it is not delete the records in Production?

**Code:**

```
Trigger BidDeleteTrigger on Bid__c (BEFORE UPDATE)
{   

    TRY
    {
        LIST<Bid_line__c> bidline = NEW LIST<Bid_line__c>(); 
        LIST<Id> bidid = NEW LIST<Id>();
        FOR(Bid__c bidpro : Trigger.NEW)  
        {  
             IF(bidpro.Delete__c == TRUE)
             {  
                bidpro.Delete__c = FALSE;       
                bidid.add(bidpro.Id); 
             }
        }
        IF(bidid.SIZE() != 0)
        {    
            bidline = [SELECT ID FROM Bid_line__c WHERE Bid__c IN: bidid LIMIT 50000];
            IF(bidline.size() != 0)                
                DELETE bidline; 
        }
     }
     CATCH(EXCEPTION E){
         SYSTEM.DEBUG('ERROR:'+E);
     }   
}
```

Yes,I have Debug in Production I got a Exception below:

Exception:

```
31:04.975 (975279099)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[29]|System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id a3O80000001pJnxxxx; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = a3N8000000aaaa) is currently in trigger Bidpro_Details_Delete, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []
12:31:04.975 (975850995)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[29]|Database.delete(LIST<SObject>)
12:31:04.975 (975925291)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[46]|String.valueOf(Object)
12:31:04.975 (975965515)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[46]|String.valueOf(Object)
12:31:04.975 (975987895)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[46]|System.debug(ANY)
12:31:04.975 (975997242)|USER_DEBUG|[46]|DEBUG|**ERROR : Trigger BidDeleteTrigger_Delete :System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id a3O80000001pJnxxxx; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = a3N8000000aaaa) is currently in trigger Delete, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []**
12:31:04.976 (976004076)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[46]|System.debug(ANY)
```

Comment: What is the error in your debug log?

Comment: BTW, you only need the `try` block around the DML (DELETE) statement.

Comment: Can I use the Database.delete(bidline)?instated DELETE.Already try catch block are their.

Comment: Do you have a trigger running on the `Bid_Line__c` object?  Also, have you tried running this on an AFTER trigger?

Comment: Trigger run on the Bid__c Object not Bid_Line__c object.Both are different objects with look up relationship.Why this error came.Okie can I try after insert it works right?. Please let me know.

Comment: Remove the exception handling or also log the exception stacktrace. That should show how the recursion occurred. You can use a static set to keep track of the processed ids and skip them if they come up again.

Comment: "first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = a3N8000000aaaa) is currently in trigger Delete, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []**"

Answer (score 1):

Your bidline `SELECT` statement is using the IDs of your `Bid__c` object.
i.e.

```
 ... WHERE Bidline__c IN :bidid ...
```

I'm assuming `Bidline__c` is not the lookup field to the `Bid__c` object.

Try updating the `Bidline__c` in this statement to whatever the lookup field is.

i.e.

```
...  WHERE Parent_Bid__c IN :bidid ....
```

Where `Parent_Bid__c` is the name of the lookup field.

Comment: I have edited in the notepad.I didn't see the select query.Now I edited the same select query can you please check and let me know

Comment: Hi All I have edited the question can you please check

Comment: Its strange that it is working in Sandbox but if you look in debug log the trigger is calling recursively. Can you plz chk if there is any rollup summary field or any workflow field update?

Comment: I have compare both Sandbox and Production Object's one of the Roll Up Summary field on the Bid__c Object but not in Sandbox. Now I have modified the Trigger **AFTER UPDATE** then it working as I accepted.Thank for ALL.